# Google Calendar API taking long time to inserting - PHP

Tags: php, csv, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, xlsx

I have an issue with importing data into different calendars using the APIs of Google (in PHP).

I have a .csv of 150+ rows, and i need each one of them to be an event in a specific calendar, but loading each one takes 3-4 seconds, so the script goes out of time.
I also have another .csv with 50+ rows, and each of those have to be a calendar alone.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: the loading time problem is not to load them in memory, or onto the DB. The creation of the event itself takes a couple seconds each.

Comment: run it from the command line?

Comment: I didn't manage to make it work, and my hosting doesn't support it. The only solution I managed to find is to run a php script every - like - 10 rows and then autorefresh to the next 10 so that it doesn't run out of time

Comment: that's annoying. Is this a task you will need to repeat regularly? If so it might be worth considering moving to a hosting account that supports CRON jobs. You can get one very cheaply.

Comment: No, it's just the initial importation of data. I'm building a new "employee management system" with my internship and i need to import the old data to the new system

Comment: If it's a one-off job why not run it from your localhost's command line then? Why does it need to be on the server? Just export the CSV to your PC and run from there. Then there are no timeout issues.

Comment: Sorry for the noob-ish question (and i'm afraid i'm going off-topic), but how do i do it? Executing "php myScript.php" simply outputs the source code in the prompt. p.s. Yes, I have installed PHP in the local machine, but do i need something like Apache too?

Comment: There's some guidance here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php which you may have found already. I think the exact setup required depends a bit on your O/S. There are a few previous StackOverflow questions on the topic too which come up on google.